# Windows XP Pro - Can't install VLC Player?

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus

ASUS EEEPC with Windows XP Pro. I am logged in as Administrator, I download and install VLC. Everything looks normal and the install seems to proceed normally. Except the program is never installed.  I notice that NOD32 is complaining about the update password, which I should fix of course. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the portable version, since it does not have a setup, you will be able to run it

Comment: That would have solved the problem during our presentation.  I'll use that next time!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the NOD32 product (as in I've never used it). Does it offer some sort of registry protector or is it just antivirus scanning? Is the update password for getting updates only or working in general? Is it trial version or paid?

Comment: Yes I think it does offer a registry protector. But I've installed other apps on this machine (MS Office 2007, mostly). Paid version, update pwd is required for getting updates.

Answer (score 0):

How much space do you have left on the eee?
Mine sometimes complains about a lack of memory too - perhaps that's the issue. Do you have anything else open aside from NOD?

Comment: Yeah - that would be a likely suspect. But there is plenty of free disk on this one...